I installed pytest via terminal when i run it my computer doesn't recognize it
I ran pytest in Vscode terminal it was not recognized please help
I check python version for and pytest test I verified the installation location of pytest I am using admin also name of the file is test_sample.py
this is the error:
pytest : The term 'pytest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,     
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pytest
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pytest:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


As the verify that the path is correct error suggests you should check  your OS PATH variable and make it include the pytest command directory.

Are you using a virtual environment ? If yes, are you sure your vscode terminal is using this correct environment, verify the interpreter.
